# sort a huge array

Tags: algorithm

what is the best way to sort a huge array. say I have 1G RAM, array is 16G. 
What is the most efficient method to do this? 
I got enough disk for files.

Comment: Which programming language are you intending to use? You seem to be most concerned about memory usage. What's the state of the virtual memory; do you even need to care? *What's your definition of 'best'* - time, minimized swapping, or other?

Comment: @p.campbell not a practical problem. Focus on algorithm and solution. Thanks :)

Comment: @p.campbell yeah kinda. I met another big file question before. so came up with this one. still preparing for Amazon interview. LOL~

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Split into chunks and sort 512MB at a time into 32 files.  Then do a streaming merge sort of the files into one file.

Answer (score 4):

If it's an array of integers, you can get by with a naive radix sort `(O(n))` and use almost no RAM at all. First question would be "What kind of data is it?". If its arbitrary data, then an external mergesort is probably your best option.

-tjw